# Upgrading FadeIn Pro

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, software-installation

I'm trying to update screenwriting software FadeIn Pro from 4.0.19 to 4.1.0. I've tried what I *think* should work to upgrade the app, as well as a few other attempts, but nothing has worked so far.

I am brand-spanking new to Linux. I built my first Linux machine only a few weeks ago and I'm diving in head first. This means I am likely missing something obvious, but I don't know what.

I appreciate any suggestions, especially if they're written in the simplest terms, given how green I am with Linux.

More information:

These are the instructions from the site:

> Compiled binaries for Linux. Download and open either the .deb (Debian, Ubuntu, etc.) or .rpm (Red Hat, Fedora, SUSE, etc.) package. There are separate packages for 64-bit (amd64) and 32-bit (i386) systems. The program will be installed to /usr/bin/fadein, with resources in /usr/share/fadein/.

I'm quite sure I've downloaded the correct package and have extracted it correctly. (I did manage to install it, after all.)

fadein-linux-amd64-4.1.0

When I try: sudo apt-get upgrade fadein, the terminal tells me the current version (4.0.19) is the newest version. This is false, but Ubuntu is quite insistent on the matter.

Thank you for your help, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the software does not come from a repository which was added to the sources used by `apt`, `apt` doesn't know about the new version.

You have to download the new version from the website manually and install it afterwards over the old version with `sudo apt install /path/to/fadein-linux-amd64-demo.deb`.

Comment: That did it. I thought it might be something like that, but I didn't have the confidence to hack my way through it. Thank you both!